# Moment of inertia $I_x$ bounded by $z=0$, $x=0$, $y^2=x^3$, $y+z=1$, $z-y=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

Given the bounds
$$z=0,\quad x=0,\quad y^2=x^3,\quad y+z=1,\quad z-y=1.$$
I tried finding the volume using the following bounds
$$\begin{cases}
-1\le y\le 0\\
0\le x\le y^{2/3}\\
0\le z\le 1+x^{3/2}
\end{cases}$$

Next I calculated the integral which gave me the right answer as in the textbook, but is this a coincidence?

$$V=\int _{-1}^0\int _0^{y^{\frac{2}{3}}}\int _0^{1+x^{\frac{3}{2}}}1dzdxdy=\frac{9}{20}$$

I next wanted to calculate the moment of inertia $I_x$ but this gave me the wrong answer

$$I_x=\frac{20m}{9}\int _{-1}^0\:\int _0^{y^{\frac{2}{3}}}\:\int _0^{1+x^{\frac{3}{2}}}\left(y^2+z^2\right)dzdxdy\:=\frac{50m}{77}.$$

The answer should've been $$I_x=\frac{29m}{77}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems when calculating the volume you are missing something. Indeed $y$ can vary from $-1$ to $1$. First let's assume $-1\le y\le 0$. In this case we only need the constraint $z-y=1$. The volume of this part is:
$$\int_{-1}^0 \int_{0}^{\sqrt[3] {y^2}}\int_{0}^{1+y}dzdxdy=\frac {9}{40};$$

and for $0\le y\le 1$, we need $y+z=1$. The volume of this part is:

$$\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{\sqrt[3] {y^2}}\int_{0}^{1-y}dzdxdy=\frac {9}{40};$$

hence the total volume is $\frac {9}{20}$.

To compute $I_x$, use the same approach. Therefore the answer is:

$$\frac {20}{9}(\int_{-1}^0 \int_{0}^{\sqrt[3] {y^2}}\int_{0}^{1+y}y^2+z^2\ {} dzdxdy \ {} +\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{\sqrt[3] {y^2}}\int_{0}^{1-y}\ {y^2+z^2} \ dzdxdy);$$

which is equal to: $$\frac {20}{9}(\frac{261}{3080}+\frac{261}{3080})=\frac{29}{77}.$$